# Is it possible to have regex like following

Tags: javascript

Special characters, Alpha numeric is **ALLOWED** in a string.
But Only Special characters in a string is not **allowed**

Example :

1. Hell$,@123 - **allowed**
2. #&@ - **not allowed**

Answer (score 0):

You just need a regex that requires at least one alphanumeric.

```
RegExp(/[A-z0-9]/g).test("Hell$,@12")
>> true
RegExp(/[A-z0-9]/g).test("1!")
>> true
RegExp(/[A-z0-9]/g).test("@!")
>> false
```